# Integrate an angular app as a jira plugin

Tags: angular, plugins, jira

I've already developed an angular application and i want to connect it to jira.. what i mean is that i want to make it part of my jira dashboard. I did some research but I couldn't find anything useful.
This was probably the nearest thing to what I'm looking for but it's too complicated:
https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/build-a-hello-world-app-in-jira/
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Every component in a dashboard or a Jira is a part of a plugin and you can implement custom plugins for Jira.

You may check online examples about `Atlassian SDK` or `Jira Plugin Development` or you may want to see the following [Atlassian Developer page](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/create-a-helloworld-plugin-project/) as a starter. Also, [Atlassian repo](https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/workspace/projects/PROJ) has some quality content.

As a prior knowledge; Atlassian implementations are using Java as language via Spring and Maven frameworks.

So, what are the options that you have in order to use your Angular app in Jira:

1. You may try to create a plugin which shows your Angular page as web content.
2. You may try a simple plugin which includes the URL of your Angular page inside dashboard or project. Thus, user can click that link from Jira and can open your Angular page.
3. Instead of implementing an SDK plugin, you can place the URL of your application inside the dashboard so that user can open it on a new page.

Other than that, you cannot integrate the Angular page to the Jira directly.